# How to create a list menu from the list Activity Class,,,what i'm doing wrong???help out

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-activity, listactivity

//**MAIN ACTIVITY JAVA FILE: IN this java file i create a various classess below shown one class for example(Textplay) i want to create the list Activity in the menu list,,when i run this code in emulator i seen application forced clossly what i'm doing wrongly**//

```
   package com.example.eeeramsong;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class menu extends ListActivity{
String classes[]={"Counter","Textplay","example3","example4","example5"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>    
 (menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese=classes[position];
    try{
    Class classss=Class.forName("com.example.eeramsong." + cheese);
    Intent inte=new Intent(menu.this,classss);
    startActivity(inte);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }




/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

**SECOND JAVA FILE:**

```
  package com.example.eeeramsong;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.ToggleButton;
  public class Textplay extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);
    Button chkb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.txtbutton);
    ToggleButton chktog=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.txttog);
    EditText tex= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtext);
    TextView txtview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txttv);
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}
```

**XML FILE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="30dp" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:password="true"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:hint="Type anything...:-)"
    />
<LinearLayout 
android:weightSum="100"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="20dp">
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/txtbutton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:text="Command"
    />
<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/txttog"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:checked="false"
    />

</LinearLayout>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/txttv"
    android:text="Invalid"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to           
 instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.errortest/com.example.errortest.Menu}:  
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.errortest.Menu in loader 
 dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.errortest-1.apk]
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at   
 android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at   
 android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at 
 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at 
 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at          
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at 
 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at 
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at   
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at 
 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at    
 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native   
 Method)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
 com.example.errortest.Menu in loader  
 dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.errortest-1.apk]
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at 
 dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at  
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at 
 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at   
 android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     at               
 android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
 03-25 17:39:06.102: E/AndroidRuntime(335):     ... 11 more
```

**MANIFEST FILE**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.errortest"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="Textplay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post the logcat. and there i no use of main method in the activities. and is the full MainActivity posted coz i don't see `public class MainActivity extends ListActivty`

Comment: Post your Stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Please add Menu Activity in your project menifeast file.

Answer (score 0):

Your have created a normal java class so add the activity details in manifest file which is missing.